# How to know the pages where an image is displayed in wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress

I am not sure if this is possible since I've been googling about this issue but I couldn't find any solution. I am on media of wp-admin, and I am trying to view the pages where a specific image has been used. I am a developer and I don't know how it is done. Anybody help?

```
 Example:

 image.jpg

 has been displayed in :

 www.mydomain.com/

 www.mydomain.com/page-1 

 www.mydomain.com/page-2
```

I don't know how. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to the database, you can make a search for all occurrences of the image link in all posts and pages. To do this you need to get the link of the image through the admin menu. You will have something like:

```
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/image.png
```

The post and page content are located in the table `wp_posts` (Replace "wp_" with your table prefix if not using the default). Now you can do a query like:

```
SELECT `ID`, `post_title`, `guid` FROM `wp_posts` 
WHERE `post_content` LIKE  '%http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/image.png%'
```

This will give you the post titles and their links. Should be something like:

```
ID  post_title      guid
9   Post Title 1    http://www.example.com/?page_id=9
20  Post Title 2    http://www.example.com/?page_id=20
```

Comment: the `%` are for fuzzy matching, so you could drop the `http://example.com` to get anything that matches the path

Comment: Note that the SQL query does not list thumbnails but only the original image, which often might not be the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

In Media change the view to List view where you will be able to see which image is attached to which post.

Comment: This answer does not solve the question: In case a **single image** is embedded **in multiple pages/posts** then the column "Uploaded to" of the Media Library in list view only shows one page where that image is embedded, but not all of them. Though I don't know by what ruleset. Where it was embedded first? Last? Or maybe where the flag "attached to" points to?

Answer (score -3):

All the images are uploaded under
`wp-content/uploads` folder
you will inspect using firebug and get the path of the image.
Thanks

Comment: sorry but I am looking for the "PAGES" or "URL" where images are displayed.